# R error: data.frame(...) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1, despite the dataframe to append to being empty

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with three different datasets corresponding to three different experiment setups that have the same structure in columns but with a different number of rows (observations).

for each dataset, I want to do a normality check before testing the data. The datasets are separated, the two data columns to check normality on is determined based on two criteria from other columns present in the dataset (basically: if Column X is "yes" or "no", *and* if Column Z is "Characteristic A"). My code for doing this is as follows:

```
# create empty dataset to restore results in
results_df <- data.frame(DataframeName = character(),
                         TestType = character(),
                         WStatistic = numeric(),
                         PValue = numeric(),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## results_df is 0 observations of 4 variables


Exp_list <- list(Exp1, Exp2, Exp3)

## Exp1 is 1232 observations of 13 variables
## Exp2 is 888 observations of 13 variables
## Exp3 is 1438 of 13 variables



# function to perform normality tests and save results
perform_normality_test <- function(df, dataframe_name) {
  if (nrow(df) < 3) { 
    cat("Insufficient data for the normality test. \n")
  } else { 
    shapiro_result_A <- shapiro.test(df$ColumnA)
    
      results_df <<- rbind(results_df, 
                           data.frame(DataframeName = dataframe_name,
                                      TestType = "ColumnA",
                                      WStatistic = shapiro_result_pos$statistic,
                                      PValue = shapiro_result_A$p.value,
                                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
      
      
      cat( "Shapiro-Wilk normality test for Column A column: \n")
      cat("W statistic:", shapiro_result_A$statistic, "\n")
      
      cat("p-value:", shapiro_result_A$p.value, "\n\n")
      
      shapiro_result_B <- shapiro.test(df$ColumnB)
      
      results_df <<- rbind(results_df, 
                           data.frame(DataframeName = dataframe_name,
                                      TestType = "ColumnB",
                                      WStatistic = shapiro_result_B$statistic,
                                      PValue = shapiro_result_B$p.value,
                                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
      
      cat("Shapiro-Wilk normality test for ColumnB column:\n")
      cat("W statistic:", shapiro_result_B$statistic, "\n")
      cat("p-value:", shapiro_result_B$p.value, "\n")
    }
}

# iterate through the lsit of dataframes and perform normality test
for (i in 1:length(Exp_list)) { 
  df <- Exp_list[[i]]
  dataframe_name <- names(Exp_list)[i]
  cat("Performing normality tests for dataframe: ", dataframe_name, "\n")
  perform_normality_test(df, dataframe_name)
  cat("\n")
}

print(results_df)
```

However, when I run this code, it gives me the following error message:

```
Error in data.frame(DataframeName = dataframe_name, TestType = "ColumnA", : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

I can't figure out the error code, because Results_df is empty to begin with, and I am only trying to add in data. Does someone have any experience with this? I was thinking that I should fill up the two smaller datasets with NA values until the size of the biggest dataset, but that has no effect on the shapiro test outcomes, which are the ones ultimately stored in the results_df, correct?

I don't know what to try otherwise anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) Defining your function to require the presence of `results_df` in the calling environment is sloppy, can make troubleshooting significantly difficult, and completely breaks reproducibility. (2) Iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Comment: As the error states, this doesn’t have anything to do with `results_df` - The error is in the data frame `dataframe_name`

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this error when requesting a column name that did not exist.
Since the column did not exist, no rows were returned.

Simple typo.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35263860)